# Can I align those circles of unordered list with html by tricks?

Tags: html, css

I was asked to make the copy of these with only html :
[image: Task Photo]

I tried to do it use this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Table-2
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="20%" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Webpage</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p align="center">
          <b><u>Ordered and Unordered list</u></b>
        </p>
        <p>
          <ul align="right" type="circle">
            <li>NDC</li>
            <li>DC</li>
            <li>DCC</li>
        </p>
        </ul>
        </p>
        <p>
          <ol align="left" tyle="1" start="7">
            <li>NDC</li>
            <li> DC</li>
            <li>DCC</li>
          </ol>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

But the circles of unordered list is not aligning. Can I do it using any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are! You can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
    Table-2
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table width="20%" border="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
    <p>Webpage</p>
    
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
    
    <p align="center"><b><u>Ordered and Unordered list</u></b></p>
    <ul type="circle" style="margin-left: 65%;">
    <li>NDC</li>
    <li>DC</li>
    <li>DCC</li></p>
    </ul>
    <p><ol style="margin-left: 20%;" type="1" start="7">
    <li>NDC</li>
    <li> DC</li>
    <li>DCC</li>
    </ol></p>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

All you need to do is use the `margin-left` property.

If you want to be a bit more formal with you code, you can do this:

Create a file called style.css, and add this code in it:

```
ul[type="circle"] {
    margin-left: 65%;
}

ol[type="1"] {
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Then, go back to your HTML, and add this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table-2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table width="20%" border="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
    <p>Webpage</p>
    
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
    
    <p align="center"><b><u>Ordered and Unordered list</u></b></p>
    <ul type="circle">
    <li>NDC</li>
    <li>DC</li>
    <li>DCC</li></p>
    </ul>
    <p><ol type="1" start="7">
    <li>NDC</li>
    <li> DC</li>
    <li>DCC</li>
    </ol></p>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```